# Max Value of a column in the same year and month

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have to columns I want to analyse, visits and dates. I now want the max visits of a month. The data ranges over multiple years.

```
+--------+--------+---+  
|Date    |Visits  |Max|  
|31.12.19|77      |77 |  
|01.01.20|47      |   |  
|02.01.20|121     |   |  
|03.01.20|133     |133|  
...  
|01.02.20|21      |   |  
|02.02.20|135     |135|
+--------+--------+---+
```

Comment: Create a Pivot Table, group by dates as you wish (months, years of both of them) and get the max value easily selecting Max instead of sum (default option)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create easily a Pivot Table:

[image]

> [More about Pivot
>   Tables](https://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html)

To create this Pivot Table I did:

1. Date field into Rows Section and grouped by Years and Months
2. Visits field into Values section and selected option MAX

> [Group Pivot Tables
>   Items](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/group-pivot-table-items.html)